# Conditions present after solving for x

Tags: quadratics, fractions

The question asked me to solve

$\dfrac {x^2+2x-8}{x^2-x-2}=3$

The answer is $x=0.5$, which I worked out, but in the answers it says that I must state the condition that $x≠2$ to get full marks. Why is this condition present? How can I recognise when a condition exists, when I encounter similar problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When solving this equation you assume that $x^2-x-2\ne{0}\implies{}x\ne{}-1,2$. 
In general while solving an equation make sure that the denominator is not equal $0$.

Comment: I see, so because $x^2-x-2$ is denominator, it cannot be 0?

Comment: @Mercury: Exactly! :)